How to Connect an Internal Load Balancer (ILB) to a Global Load Balancer (GLB) in GCP Without Using Network Endpoint Groups (NEGs)?
I'm trying to connect an Internal Load Balancer (ILB) to a Global Load Balancer (GLB) in GCP. My ILB is set up using a Kubernetes Ingress YAML file, and I need to map it as a backend for the GLB. However, I found that Network Endpoint Groups (NEGs) don't support internal load balancers (as mentioned here). https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/network-endpoint-groups/create#--network-endpoint-type
Is there an alternative way to route traffic from a GLB to an ILB, or another solution to make this setup work? Any advice would be appreciated!
